# fill and group bar graphs by different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create faceted `geom_bar` graphs with the following charactaristics:

1. The proportion of each answer **per question** is shown
2. Each bar is colored according to the **response**
3. The plot is faceted by **question**

I seem to be able to do any two of the conditions, but not all 3.

**Question:**

Is there a way to facet and calculate proportions using one variable, but colour/fill based on another variable?

**Code:**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Question = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each = 5),
  Resp     = sample(c('Yes', 'No', 'Unsure', NA), 15, T, c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.1)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

# Plot 1: grouping by question to get the right proportions, but has no colour

ggplot(df, aes(x = Resp, fill = Resp)) +
  stat_count(aes(y = ..prop.., group = Question)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_wrap(~ Question)

# Plot 2: grouping by response to get colour, but has wrong proportions

ggplot(df, aes(x = Resp, fill = Resp)) +
  stat_count(aes(y = ..prop.., group = Resp)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_wrap(~ Question)
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to calculate the proportions and then plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  count(Question, Resp) %>%
  group_by(Question) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Resp, n, fill = Resp) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~Question)
```

[image]

Comment: pity I have to use tidyverse, I was hoping for a within-ggplot way, but this does work for me, so thanks :)

Comment: I did have to change the order of count and group_by as in my real data I'm also grouping by a third variable, but other than that this works

Answer (score 3):

This is a "ggplot2-only" option:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Resp)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., group = Question, fill = factor(..x..)), position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Response", labels = c("No", "Unsure", "Yes", "NA")) +
  facet_wrap(~ Question)
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, I can't get this to work for me, they all stay grey still

Comment: On your sample data it works flawlessly for me. Do you get any warnings?

Comment: no error, just grey :( do I need the `scale_fill_discrete`? or can I use `scale_fill_manual`? which is what I currently use in my actual plots to specify the colour

Comment: scale fill manual should work, too. Maybe your real data has different classes than your sample data? Or there is a typo somwhere around `fill = ` or `group =`. I can just guess..

Answer (score 2):

Plot without facet

```
df$n <- 1

df <- df %>% group_by(Question, Resp) %>% summarise(n = sum(n))

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Question), y=n, fill=Resp)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Plot with facet

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Question, Resp) %>% summarise(n = sum(n)) %>% mutate(prop = n/5)

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Resp), y=prop, fill=Resp)) + geom_col() + facet_wrap(~Question)
```

[image]